# @font-face declaration doesn't follow the fontspring bulletproof syntax error

Tags: html, css, font-face

I have been trying to change my fonts using font-face rule but it isn't working. It keeps showing "@font-face declaration doesn't follow the fontspring bulletproof syntax" everytime. I have gone through the web but haven't found any right solution?
Here is my code:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "MyFont";
  src: url(fonts/Benne-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
}
h1 {
  font-family: "MyFont";
}
```

What should i do?

Comment: Is the url in `url(...)` in quotes?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if any other linters than CSS Lint check for this but this is a reference to the `?#iefix` string used to work around an old Internet Explorer bug with parsing font URLs, which [Fontspring calls the bulletproof `@font-face` syntax](https://blog.fontspring.com/2011/02/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax).

If you're not supporting old versions of IE, you can safely ignore this warning, and I would strongly urge you to disable CSS Lint and use something like stylelint instead. CSS Lint has not been updated in years, and the bulletproof syntax is a product of its time, so is no longer needed today.

If you *are* supporting old IE, or can't disable CSS Lint and want to make this warning go away:

```css
@font-face {
font-family: "MyFont";
src: url("fonts/Benne-Regular.ttf?#iefix") format("truetype");
}
h1 {
font-family: "MyFont";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your format seems right, as Roddy mention check your url, here is your code with Benne font using google cdn

```css
@font-face {
font-family: "MyFont";
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/benne/v10/L0xzDFAhn18E6Wj2nN8.woff2) format('woff2');
}
h1 {
font-family: "MyFont";
}
```

```html
<h1>test</h1>
```